# FLTK Exif data from an image

Tags: c++, exif, fltk

Is there a fltk class/function that deals with extracting exif data from an image? Is there code or any commands? Ive searched all over the internet, and could find nothing.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such class in [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org), and probably there will never be. Dealing with Exif data should be in another library that deals with image formarts, not a GUI toolkit.

What I would do if I were you is this: Link my FLTK application with Magick++ (http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) and use ImageMagick C++ API to manipulate Exif data.